# illegal state exception crashes app when switching from Activity to RosActivity

Tags: ros, client-rosjava, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My main activity is a rosActivity where I execute various nodes in my init function. I have an Android activity that displays various utility information and I can switch from my RosActivity to my Activity without any problems. When I return to my RosActivity from my Activity the following error occurs:

```
W/dalvikvm( 6308): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4b1f8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308): java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at org.ros.android.RosActivity.startMasterChooser(RosActivity.java:115)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at org.ros.android.RosActivity.access$100(RosActivity.java:38)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at org.ros.android.RosActivity$NodeMainExecutorServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(RosActivity.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1068)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1085)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6308):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm running on a phone and using a lot of memory so the original RosActivity is almost certainly being destroyed when I switch to my Activity. Are the RosNodes connected to their rosActivity in a way where they cannot be recalled when their RosActivity is destroyed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37746/illegal-state-exception-crashes-app-when-switching-from-activity-to-rosactivity/) by [dirkmcpherson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2756/dirkmcpherson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a bug for this: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=123

Feel free to star it so that you will be notified when it is addressed.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/22505/kevin.kuei.0321@gmail.com/) on 2015-11-12**:
Hi, I got the same problem. Did you solve the problem then??